# Visual Studio 2012 Report: Can I choose where a subreport to grow?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, report, reporting, subreport

I'm creating a report in Visual Studio 2012, which will be printed and folded in half. Thus I've placed the actual pages side by side in the report. 
The problem is that I need to place a subreport into the first page (on the left), which must grow into the second page (on the right), instead of down, creating a new report page. 
Is there a way to choose where a subreport to grow, or is there a workaround for such a report (two actual pages per page)?

Comment: I've tackled the problem by creating two subreports - one on each page. I've limited the number of items on the first one, so they would fit, and filled the second page with the rest of the items. I don't like it, but it works.